# Dependency injection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, design-patterns

I am learning the constructor injection from this source https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177649/what-is-constructor-injection

I am happy that I am able to understand it. However, I have a basic doubt related to interface and class and injection of interface in the constructor.

In specific, I am not able to understand how we inject the interface without creating the object Sword as in first snippet.

```
class Samurai
{
    readonly IWeapon weapon;
    public Samurai() 
    {
        this.weapon = new Sword();
    }
    public void Attack(string target) 
    {
        this.weapon.Hit(target);
    }
}
```

In this below snippet, they claim it does the same thing as above code, however, with loose coupling.

```
class Samurai
{
    readonly IWeapon weapon;
    public Samurai(IWeapon weapon) 
    {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }
    public void Attack(string target) 
    {
        this.weapon.Hit(target);
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me understand why we are not creating object of Sword using `"new"` keyword in the second snippet and how it functions without that? Are the above two snippets same? And also, how is this a lose coupling?

Comment: In the second snippet, an IWeapon (MAYBE a Sword, but maybe something else) is created externally, before the Samurai, and passed in to the constructor. This way, you can make a Samurai with any IWeapon. In the first example, you're stuck with using only a Sword, and if you want to change that, you have to change the code in the Samurai class. Clearly, this is undesirable! You are right that AT SOME POINT a concrete weapon (like Sword) must be created. With dependency injection, the difference is WHERE it is created, and how it is passed to and stored in the Samurai.

Comment: Like @Baldrick said, your not creating it "in" the class. However you are still doing a "new" somewhere ..just not in that class (probably new Weapon(), which implements IWeapon)

Comment: The in the second example the Samurai is not "coupled" to the new sword because the weapon is injected removing the dependency on the sword.

Comment: Thanks Baldrick. But in the example in the source link, have they created it externally? Can you give me some example of how to use this with maybe two different weapons, it will be easy for me to understand. A small snippet structure would help.

Comment: btw if you don't want dependency hell despite "so-called" IOC ..don't put your interfaces in a subfolder of your project. Create a dll project that "only" contains interfaces ..you'll understand when you start creating project A, that references project B, that references project C which depends on project A ..etc :-)

Comment: Thanks Robert, Stink, Baldrick. I will understand it better if I create that and test myself. Robert, what is the difference between ICO and DI? Is there any?

Comment: This got me thinking... does this mean that dependency injection relies on polymorphism to work?

Comment: I was gonna say they are the same ..but here's a better explanation http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131451/difference-between-dependency-injection-di-inversion-of-control-ioc

Comment: @Robert: Thank you, will read that now. But as Stink asks, is it a kind of run time (Overriding) polymorphism?

Comment: No clue, i never got the terms of all this theoretical stuff right. To me as long as you are doing object oriented programming i'd say you are doing polymorphism anyways, but i'm sure i'm wrong ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx

Comment: @Robert: Well I am sort of newbie :P So really learning day by day in a small increment. :)

Comment: @Robert: One last question, can you please give me two real time example of where we use DI? (Say Banking application)

Comment: so for programming starters => "Hello World" same way DI starters => "Samurai/Weapon" :)

Comment: I'm not a noob, i know my practical stuff, but i never studied computer science, algorithms, design patterns and all that stuff, so i can't really help here much. I know what a interface, inheritance, abstract and all that stuff is and how to use it ..but to put the correct term on it ...

Comment: no problem, have fun !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passing in an implementation of IWeapon allows you to have as many versions of a weapon as you desire with whatever object you decide to create, as long as it shares the same public interface.

You could create a Gun or a Sword object that uses the IWeapon interface and your Samurai class wouldn't care. Using the `new` keyword inside your class prevents you from being able to do that. Instead, you are forced to only use the single implementation that Samurai knows about (because it created it). So if you wanted to add another weapon later you'd have to modify the Samurai class. Implementing Samurai like that is especially gross if you're exposing it as an API to other developers because they are not going to want to muck around in your code.

So you'd do something like this:

```
Gun gun = new Gun();
Samurai samurai = new Samurai(gun);
```

The implementation would look like this:

```
public class Gun : IWeapon { // Implementing IWeapon, and typecasting the class into a Weapon
   public Attack(string target) {
     // Perform attack logic here
   }
}
```

Your interface looks like this:

```
public interface IWeapon {
  void Attack(string target);
}
```

Comment: Walt thank you, but could you please give me a small structure as to where we create the Sword object and or gun and use it? I am new here and don't know much. :(